Why does the css function mod() 2 show the results 2 sometimes when the browser window is resized?
The code shows 0 and 1, and why does it shows 2 sometimes?
My browser is Microsoft Edge v130, and Chrome v130 does the same.


@property --vw {
  syntax: "<length>";
  inherits: true;
  initial-value: 100vw;
}
:root {
  --w: mod(tan(atan2(var(--vw), 1px)), 2);
}
body::before {
  counter-reset: w var(--w);
  content: counter(w);
}
<body></body>




When you use calc or another CSS function, it can be hard to see what the computed value is. If you do getComputedStyle(document).getPropertyValue("--w") you just get the formula, not the value.
One trick to see what the computed value is, is to assign it to a real property. Since your --w property hasn't got a unit, you could assign it to line-height.
body {
  font-size: 1px;
  line-height: var(--w);
}

Now, you can see the value, which might for example be 1.99. The counter-reset property only takes integers and 2 is "close enough".
You can use round() to round the number (up, down, nearest integer or to-zero):
:root {
  --w: mod(round(nearest, tan(atan2(var(--vw), 1px)) ), 2);
}

(The round() can also go outside the mod(), whatever makes sense to you)

Thank you for your answers, I got a fish with a fishing gear.

The reason your code sometimes shows 2 instead of 0 or 1 is due to floating-point numbers.
You can try using min
    :root {
  --w: round(mod(nearest, tan(atan2(var(--vw), 1px)) ), 2);
}

or
:root {
      --w: mod(round(nearest, tan(atan2(var(--vw), 1px)) ), 2);
    }


Did you actually test out your answer before posting? I'm still receiving 2's (on Firefox 132.0.1 - 64-bit) — Unsure what you mean with the floating-point numbers. Care to elaborate?

Thank you, I got it. The middle result of tan-atan2 is a float number while counter-reset receives int.
